# TimelineMax reverse tweens once

Tags: javascript, reverse, timeline, gsap

I'm wondering if there is a way to reverse tweens inside a timeline once they finished animating. I want to scale elements and change their color. After that I want to reverse the animation. 
I tried with `yoyo()` but that method unfortunately plays the animations 3 times even when I set `repeat: 1` (it animates 1-2-3-3-2-1-1-2-3-3-2-1).

```
    introTimeline.append(  TweenMax.to($(".Element"), 1, {scale: 2, 
    fill: "red", ease: Power2.easeIn, repeat: 1, yoyo: 
    true})  );
```

All I need is 1-2-3-3-2-1 for each tween in the timeline …

Is timeline the wrong way to approach this?

Come on does really know an answer to such a simple question … ?

Comment: How about `repeat: 0` or `repeat:false`?

Comment: @GrahamPHeath Then it just animates 1-2-3 and stops. I need 1-2-3-3-2-1. I'm really confused why this simple thing has to be so hard in greensock or if I'm just too dumb to find it …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just reverse the animation once the tween is complete. Use the following code:

```
var tl = new TimelineMax({
  onComplete:complete,
});


tl.to("img", 3, {rotation:360, transformOrigin:"150px 150px", ease:Linear.easeNone});

function complete(tl) {
  tl.restart(); // 0 sets the playhead at the end of the animation
}
```